# PHP- preg_replace on hex char

Tags: php, preg-replace, chr

i have a string, like this:

`'<indirizzo>Via Universit\E0 4</indirizzo>'`

Whit HEX char... i need string become:

`'<indirizzo>Via Università 4</indirizzo>'`

So, i use: 
`$text= preg_replace('/(\\\\)([a-f0-9]{2})/imu', chr(hexdec("$2")),  $text);`

But dont work because hexdec dont use value of $2 (that is 'E0'), but use only value '2'.
So hexdex("2") is "2" and chr("2") isnt "à"

What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text='<indirizzo>Via Universit\E0 4</indirizzo>';

function cb($match) {
    return html_entity_decode('&#'.hexdec($match[1]).';');
}
$text= preg_replace_callback('/\\\\([a-f0-9]{2})/imu', 'cb', $text);

echo $text;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your `chr(hexdec())` as a callback. Just calling those functions and suppling the result as parameter to `preg_replace` doesn't do it.

```
preg_replace_callback('/\\\([a-f0-9]{2})/imu',
                      function ($match) { return chr(hexdec($match[1])); },
                      $text)
```

Having said that, there are probably better ways to do what you want to do overall.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
<?php
$str = preg_replace('/\\([a-f0-9]{2})/imue', '"\x$1"', '<indirizzo>Via Universit\E0 4</indirizzo>');
```